# Support for templating languages?

Tags: micronaut

Just got M1 and tried the Hello World app. Very cool.

Are there plans to support HTML templating such as Velocity / Thymeleaf / etc.? The emphasis seems to be on RESTful apps, but we have need to support both modes (REST and standard web controllers).

Comment: This actually doesn't seem that hard to do. Looks like it is just a matter of wiring in the Thymeleaf filter as per the guide @ https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#creating-and-configuring-the-template-engine. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Just came across this in the user guide: "The design of the HTTP server in Micronaut is optimized for interchanging messages between Microservices, typically in JSON, and is not intended as a full server-side MVC framework. For example, there is currently no support for server-side views or features typical of a traditional server-side MVC framework."

Any chance of rethinking that decision?

Comment: " Any chance of rethinking that decision? " - No, I don't think so. The decision to optimize for microservice interchange was a sound decision.  That doesn't mean support for server side views and the like can't be implemented, it means that Micronaut was optimized for something else.

Comment: None of the above is well suited for StackOverflow questions.  This is really the type of question that it makes more sense to ask the dev team and/or the community.  https://gitter.im/micronautfw/ is a good forum for discussions like that.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Makes sense to me. I'll direct future questions like this to there instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about programming per se.  It is a question about our roadmap and plans to support or not support different application architectures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this a feature request / suggestion for micronaut team. They have other channels for it. See earlier comment from OCI team

Comment: I agree. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking if a feature will be supported